# Error on compiling in Eclipse: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, eclipse

I just resumed back to working with C++ after a long time. I am using Eclipse on Macbook Pro, and I tried just making a small project of Linked Lists.

I have been getting this error when I try compile my project:
`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

This happens only if I `#include "SingleLinkedList.h"` in my main.cpp and do operations related to `SingleLinkedist`, otherwise removing the above SingleLinkedList in main, the project compiles fines. I have been looking similar questions on SO with same error, but none seem to have helped me resolve this.

Here are the class files if needed:
As far as I remember, earlier everything in the same way used to work fine on Eclipse. I just upgraded to Lion some time back, and installed the new Xcode and a new Eclispe, and now been facing weird issues instead of concentrating on coding.

**SingleLinkedList.cpp**

```
#include "SingleLinkedList.h"

template<class T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::~SingleLinkedList()
{
    Node<T> *temp = head;
    while(head!=0)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = temp->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::addToHead(int item)
{
    head = new Node<T>(item, head);
    if (tail==0)
        tail = head;
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::addToTail(int item)
{
    if(tail!=0)
    {
    tail->next = new Node<T>(item);
    tail = tail->next;
    }
    else
        head = tail = new Node<T>(item);
}

template <class T>
int SingleLinkedList<T>::deletefromHead()
{
    int e1 = head->info;
    Node<T> *temp = head;
    if(head ==tail)
    {
    head = tail = 0;
    }
    else
        head = temp->next;
    delete temp;
    return e1;
}

template <class T>
int SingleLinkedList<T>::deletefromTail()
{
    int e1 = tail->info;
    if(head == tail)
    {
        delete head;
        head = tail = 0;
    }
    else{
        Node<T> *temp = head;
        while(temp->next != tail)
            temp = temp->next;
        delete tail;
        tail = temp;
        tail->next = 0;
    }
    return e1;
}

template <class T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::deleteNode(int item)
{
    if(head!=0) {
        if(head == tail && head->info){ //If this is the only item in the linked list
            delete head;
            head = tail = 0;
        }
        else if (item == head->info){
            Node<T> *temp = head;
            head = temp->next;
            delete temp;
        }
        else{
            Node<T> *temp = head;
            while(temp->next->info != item && temp->next !=0 ){
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            if(temp!=0){
                temp->next = temp->next->next;
                temp = temp->next;
                delete temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

template <class T>
bool SingleLinkedList<T>::isEmpty()
{
    return head == 0;
}

template <class T>
bool SingleLinkedList<T>::isInList(int item)const
{
    Node<T> * temp = head;
    while(temp!=0)
    {
        if(temp->info == item){
            break;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return temp->info == item;
}

template<class T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::SingleLinkedList()
{
    head = tail = 0;
}
```

**SingleLinkedList.h**

```
#include "Node.h"

#ifndef SINGLELINKEDLIST_H_
#define SINGLELINKEDLIST_H_

template <class T>
class SingleLinkedList {
public:
    SingleLinkedList();
    ~SingleLinkedList();

    bool isEmpty();
    bool isInList(int)const;

    void addToHead(int);
    void addToTail(int);
    int deletefromHead();
    int deletefromTail();
    void deleteNode(int);
private:
    Node<T> *head;
    Node<T> *tail;
};
#endif /* SINGLELINKEDLIST_H_ */
```

**main.cpp**

```
 #include <iostream>
#include "SingleLinkedList.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    SingleLinkedList<int> listfile;
    listfile.addToHead(2);
    listfile.addToHead(4);
    listfile.addToHead(6);
    listfile.addToHead(8);
    listfile.addToHead(10);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the reason this isn't working is because you don't define header files for template classes, with separate implementation, because templates dont have an implementation other than what the compiler generates. So it's incorrect c++ to have the .cpp file. Put it all inline or keep it in the header only. [see the following at the very bottom](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/)

Comment: Oh crap, I didn't see your comment at the bottom... Oh well. Good to have this marked so that others will see it quicker

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that they are in the build path so that eclipse knows to link the .cpp file to the rest of the binary. Go to project -> properties -> c++ general -> Paths and symbols -> source location and you should be able to set it from there. When you build again, make sure that the .cpp file that contains the implementation is being built by looking at the build log.

Adding your source doesn't really help much if you don't include the whole build log, just saying.

Comment: Not under C++ general either: http://i.imgur.com/S2hjc.png .Didn't find `includes` by searching in the top search box also.

Comment: Paths and symbols. And when you click that, look at the buttons on the right

Comment: @ Adam: I am not sure what path are we talking about to include in this. There seems to be already a bunch of things in here http://i.imgur.com/iVTFO.png. Will this have to be done every time for projects, or will this be a one-time setting? Another thing is that I am able to include `cstdef` in my classes and it gave me `Unresolved cstdef` error.

Comment: Well there are several answers to your several questions. The first is that, if you edit the includes, then that is global for all eclipse projects and will only need to be done once. The source location, however, is build configuration specific. And it depends on how you create the folder. In eclipse CDT, if you create a source folder, it will add it automatically to ALL build configurations within the eclipse project. If you just create a folder, then you have to manually specify it as a source folder by doing this. If you have multiple configurations for a single project then u live with it

Comment: But also note that you don't have to mark where you keep your headers as a source repo, because eclipse doesn't compile that, the compiler finds them from your include statements. Also, on your part about the unresolved cstdef include that was unresolved-eclipse does two things for you when it comes to error reporting wi cdt-content assist and error highlighting. Content assist might be what you are seeing. If you are able to compile it, but it still says unresolved then it is definitely content assist that you are dealing with.

Comment: And the path that you have to add is the path that contains the .cpp file that contains the function that ld is reporting as missing.

Comment: Thanks for helping this far. As you said, I added a path to the `src` where the .cpp file is. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/aYo6Q.png bu I am still getting the error. Also, I checked the build log. Link to view that: http://pastebin.com/WFyb6SZL Even after all of this, I am not sure if that's the problem since earlier I haven't' configured any such thing earlier with Eclipse while compiling my code. Any suggestions that I could try?

Comment: You added it to Includes, I previously corrected myself to say that it should be under source location. If you add it to includes, then it will not apply because you will have to use #include <something> so the reason it's not finding it is because you have the quotation marks. Put it under source location and make sure that it is under the correct build configuration.

Comment: Sorry, the reason there a mis spellings and I gave bad original directions is because I am on an iPad, away from my computer.

Comment: @ Adam: No problem with the misspelings and thanks for your patience. I checked in the Source location and the path already seems to be there. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/p3uQb.png

Comment: Next thing you should try is manually compiling it. But I should ask, if this is the case, then have you implemented the functions that the build output is complaining about, specifically addToHead, the constructor and destructor?

Comment: The code in the my original post shows the implementation of these functions ad the same is in here. I wonder wy it compile fine when I remove the `SingleLinkedList` part in my main.cpp

Comment: Oh crap. I just realized something---you have your source and header mislabeled in your original post. If its like that with the files on your drive then you might want to change it.

Comment: Oh! That was a typo in the post. Corrected that

Comment: Well, allow me to download your current project folder somehow, I'll fix it and correct the answer

Comment: I'm studying now, it might be a little while, but I will fix it before the end of the day, is that alright with you?

Comment: Yes. Not a problem as long as I get out of this thing

Comment: Adamn: Looks like I figured this out. For using the templates, the definition and implementation both have to be in the same file. Thnaks for your help!